# aggregation with group by, inner join and nested conditions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, join, group-by, aggregate

First of all I am sorry if this is a basic question, I am new to queries in MongoDB. Well, what I need is to find the latest registers for a `worker` in my `WorkerLocationContext` document and the latest register for each `sensor` in my `HeatMeasureContext` document, then join it by their `location` and then apply some filters. Here are my Schemas:

`HeatMeasureContext`:

```
const heatMeasureContextSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    sensor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MeasureSensor', required: true },
    humid: { type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true },
    globe: { type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true },
    mercury: { type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true },
    internal: { type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true },
    external: { type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true }
}, { timestamps: true })
```

`MeasureSensor`:

```
const measureSensorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: false },
    type: { type: String, required: false, uppercase: true,
        enumValues: ['MEASURE'], default: 'MEASURE' },
    location: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Location' },
    sensorType: { type: String, required: false, uppercase: true,
        enumValues: ['WORKER_ATTACHED', 'ENVIRONMENT'], default: 'ENVIRONMENT' },
    measurerType: { type: String, required: false, uppercase: true,
        enumValues: ['HEAT', 'RUID'] },
    placementType: { type: String, required: false, uppercase: true,
        enumValues: ['INTERNAL', 'EXTERNAL'], default: 'INTERNAL' }
})
```

`WorkerLocationContext`:

```
const workerLocationContextSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    sensor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'LocationSensor', required: true },
    worker: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Worker', required: true }
}, { timestamps: true })
```

`Location`

```
const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: false },
    type: { type: String, required: false, uppercase: true,
    enumValues: ['REST', 'ROOM', 'COURTYARD'], default: 'ROOM' }
})
```

`Worker`

```
const workerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    workGroup: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'WorkGroup', required: false }
})
```

I have built my query like this:

```
WorkerLocationContext.aggregate([ 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "HeatMeasureContext",
            "localField": "sensor.location._id",
            "foreignField": "sensor.location._id",
            "as": "HMContext"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "$and": [
                { "$or": [
                    { "$and": [ 
                        { 
                            "HMContext.sensor.placementType": { "$eq": "INTERNAL" }}, 
                            {"HMContext.internal": { "$gte": limit} 
                        },
                        { 
                            "HMContext.sensor.placementType": { "$eq": "EXTERNAL" }}, 
                            {"HMContext.external": { "$gte": limit} 
                        },
                    ]},
                ]},
                { "WorkerLocationContext.worker.location.type": { "$ne": "REST" } }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "null",
            "workers": {
              "$count": {}
            },
            "hmDatetime": {
                "$max": "$HMContext.createdAt"
            },
            "wlDatetime": {
                "$max": "$WorkerLocationContext.createdAt"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Basically, my goal with it is to count how many workers fit in that condition according to their current location, thus the latest registers in the context tables. I have tried some simulations in the [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/), but nothing succeeded. Is it possible to be done in MongoDB? Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

### Edit 1

Sample Data

```
- Worker
[
    { "_id": "6181de993fca98374cf901f6", "name": "Worker 1", "workGroup": "6181de3e3fca98374cf901f4", "__v": 0 },
    { "_id": "6181dec33fca98374cf901f7", "name": "Worker 2", "workGroup": "6181de4a3fca98374cf901f5", "__v": 0 },
    { "_id": "6181decc3fca98374cf901f8", "name": "Worker 3", "workGroup": "6181de4a3fca98374cf901f5", "__v": 0 },
    { "_id": "6181ded13fca98374cf901f9", "name": "Worker 4", "workGroup": "6181de4a3fca98374cf901f5", "__v": 0 }
]

- Location
[
    { "_id": "6181df293fca98374cf901fa", "name": "Location 1", "description": "Rest place", "__v": 0, "type": "ROOM" },
    { "_id": "6181df3b3fca98374cf901fb", "name": "Location 2", "description": "Room 1", "__v": 0, "type": "ROOM" }
]

- MeasureSensor
[
    { "_id": "6181e5ae3fca98374cf901fc", "name": "Sensor 1", "description": "Heat Sensor 1", "location": "6181df3b3fca98374cf901fb", "measurerType": "HEAT", "__v": 0, "placementType": "INTERNAL", "sensorType": "ENVIRONMENT", "type": "MEASURE" }
]

- LocationSensor
[
    { "_id": "6181e5f83fca98374cf901fd", "name": "Location Sensor 1", "description": "Location sensor for Location 2", "location": "6181df3b3fca98374cf901fb", "trackerType": "RFID",  "__v": 0, "sensorType": "ENVIRONMENT", "type": "LOCATION" }
]

- WorkerLocationContext
[
    { "_id": "615676c885ccad55a493503b", "updatedAt": "2021-10-01T02:47:36.207Z", "createdAt": "2021-10-01T02:47:36.207Z", "sensor": "615657572079a55f7814947b", "worker": "6153dcfb58ad722c747eb42d", "__v": 0 },
    { "_id": "618311b56b77f445ecf73277", "updatedAt": "2021-11-03T22:48:21.887Z", "createdAt": "2021-11-03T22:48:21.887Z", "sensor": "6181e5f83fca98374cf901fd", "worker": "6181de993fca98374cf901f6", "__v": 0 },
    { "_id": "618311c86b77f445ecf73278", "updatedAt": "2021-11-03T22:48:40.507Z", "createdAt": "2021-11-03T22:48:40.507Z", "sensor": "6181e5f83fca98374cf901fd", "worker": "6181decc3fca98374cf901f8", "__v": 0 }
]

- HeatMeasureContext
[
    { "_id": "61831b796b77f445ecf7327b", "updatedAt": "2021-11-03T23:30:01.640Z", "createdAt": "2021-11-03T23:30:01.640Z", "sensor": "6181e5ae3fca98374cf901fc", "mercury": 25.8, "humid": 23.5, "globe": 25.5, "external": 24.13, "internal": 24.1, "__v": 0 },
    { "_id": "61831bc96b77f445ecf7327c", "updatedAt": "2021-11-03T23:31:21.080Z", "createdAt": "2021-11-03T23:31:21.080Z", "sensor": "6181e5ae3fca98374cf901fc", "mercury": 28.6, "humid": 27.8, "globe": 27, "external": 27.72, "internal": 27.56, "__v": 0 }
]
```

### Edit 2

I had to simplify a bit my query because some expressions like `heatMeasureContex.sensor.location` wouldn't work in there (as far as I know), but here is a simple trial that is not working, and isn't even the half of what I need: [mongopplaygroung.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6TuiCw9YuCh)

Comment: Could you add sample data?

Comment: Your playground link is empty. Would be helpful if you can populate it with your sample data and your current trial.

Comment: @mohammadNaimi I just added some sample data

Comment: @ray I just added  a link with some data and a simple query, which is just a part of what I need to do and is not working .-.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QgqKG0MjgO9) what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @ray actually it is not, the counter should be equal to 2, since I have only two workers in the `Location` 3, and the only `Location` with the temperature greater than 27 at the creation time 4 (`createdAt`), is the `Location` 3.

Comment: @ray I did some progress I think, based on your query I added one more register in the `HeatMeasureContext` and got to [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V_It48r0rsQ), I think it's clearer, except that I have the impression that the `$limit` isn't limiting the correct thing... It should be limiting the last `HeatMeasureContext` per `Location` and count my number of `Worker`s based on the `WorkerLocationContext`... I am gonna have to do some more testing here with more data to better understand this query, but thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some studying and going through the [MongoDB University Aggregation Framework](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about) course (which I found out to be very good, I highly recommend), I was able to figure how to do what I needed:

```
db.heatmeasurecontexts.aggregate([
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$sensor', 
      'createdAt': {
        '$last': '$createdAt'
      }, 
      'external': {
        '$last': '$external'
      }, 
      'internal': {
        '$last': '$internal'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'measuresensors', 
      'localField': '_id', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'sensor'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$sensor'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      '$or': [
        {
          '$and': [
            {
              'sensor.placementType': {
                '$eq': 'INTERNAL'
              }
            }, {
              'internal': {
                '$gte': 27
              }
            }
          ]
        }, {
          '$and': [
            {
              'sensor.placementType': {
                '$eq': 'EXTERNAL'
              }
            }, {
              'external': {
                '$gte': 25
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 0, 
      'measure_sensor_location': '$sensor.location'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'locationsensors', 
      'localField': 'measure_sensor_location', 
      'foreignField': 'location', 
      'as': 'location_sensor'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$location_sensor'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'workerlocationcontexts', 
      'localField': 'location_sensor._id', 
      'foreignField': 'sensor', 
      'as': 'worker_location_context'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$worker_location_context'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'worker_location_context': 1, 
      'location_sensor': 1
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'workers', 
      'localField': 'worker_location_context.worker', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'worker_location_context.worker'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$worker_location_context.worker'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      '$expr': {
        '$eq': [
          '$location_sensor.location', '$worker_location_context.worker.currentLocation'
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'sensor': '$worker_location_context.sensor', 
        'sensor_location': '$location_sensor.location', 
        'worker': '$worker_location_context.worker._id', 
        'worker_location': '$worker_location_context.worker.currentLocation'
      }, 
      'createdAt': {
        '$last': '$worker_location_context.createdAt'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$count': 'workers_at_risk'
  }
])
```

I hope it may be useful eventually, despite the fact that this is a very specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can start an aggregation pipeline from the `HeatMeasureContext` collection:

1. `$match` on the `internal` or `external` field
2. `$lookup` the `WorkerLocationContext` collection using an sub-pipeline. In the sub-pipeline, `$sum` the worker count and get the `$max` `wlDatetime`
3. `$unwind` the result for further processing
4. `$group` again on `HeatMeasureContext.location`, use `$first` to get the result in sub-pipeline and `$max` to get the `hmDatetime`

```js
db.HeatMeasureContext.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $gte: [
              "$internal",
              27
            ]
          },
          {
            $gte: [
              "$external",
              27
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "WorkerLocationContext",
      let: {
        loc: "$location"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$loc",
                "$location"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$location",
            "workers": {
              "$sum": 1
            },
            "wlDatetime": {
              "$max": "$createdAt"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "workerAggResult"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$workerAggResult"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$location",
      "hmDatetime": {
        $max: "$createdAt"
      },
      "wlDatetime": {
        $first: "$workerAggResult.wlDatetime"
      },
      "workers": {
        $first: "$workerAggResult.workers"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l61jdruaYsL) for your reference.